# How to create a MPI datatype which contains only part of a class or structure?

Tags: c++, mpi

I would like to create a new data type that only specifies part of the data in a class or structure.

I already know how to use **MPI_Type_create_struct** to create a new data type that contains all data in a class:

```
class A {
public:
  double value_1;
  double value_2;
  int    value_3;
  char   value_4;
};

// Create a new data type called "MPI_derived_type"
int      count {3};
int      block_lengths[3] = {2, 1, 1};
MPI_Aint displacements[3];
displacements[0] = offsetof (A, value_1);
displacements[1] = offsetof (A, value_3);
displacements[2] = offsetof (A, value_4);
MPI_Datatype types[3] = {MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_INT, MPI_CHAR};
MPI_Type_create_struct (count, block_lengths, displacements, types, &MPI_derived_type);
MPI_Type_commit (&MPI_derived_type);
```

With above code I can send and receive all the data in `class A`. However, due to some optimization issues, I need to send only part of the data in class. For example, I just need to send `value_1` and `value_3`.

- How can I make a new data type that only contains `value_1` and `value_3` but not `value_2` and `value_4`?
- Can I use **MPI_Type_create_struct** to only specify part of structure for later communications?

Comment: simply use `MPI_Type_create_struct()` with the parts you need.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Thank you for the response. I guess this might be the solution to choose  `block_lengths[2]={1,1};` and  displacements as `displacements[0]=offsetof (A,value_1);` and `displacements[1]=offsetof (A,value_3);`. Finally, we should specify the types as `MPI_Datatype types[2]={MPI_DOUBLE,MPI_INT};`. Is it correct?

Comment: that sounds right, and if it still does not work, post your new code in a [MCVE] and I will have a look.